# Read text file into array (Storing only numerical data)

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to read specific values from the text file (below):

```
Current Online Users: 0
Total User Logins: 0
Server Uptime: 0 day, 0 hour, 0 minute
Downloaded Amount: 0.000 KB
Uploaded Amount: 0.000 MB
Downloaded Files: 0
Uploaded Files: 0
Download Bandwidth Utilization: 0.00 KB/s
Upload Bandwidth Utilization: 000.00 KB/s
```

I can read the file to an array:

```
   Dim path As String = "C:\Stats.txt"
   Dim StringArrayOfTextLines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path)
```

How do I store only the data I require in the array? I've tried split and substring but cannot work out a usable method - I need on the text after the colon for each line.

I was thinking, I only require the numerical data, can this be extracted from each line rather than just splitting into an array?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture everything after the colon you just need to split on it and take the second element of each result:

```
For Each s In StringArrayOfTextLines
    Console.WriteLine(s.Split(":")(1).Trim())
Next
```

If you want to do that as you read the data you'll need to use a `StreamReader` like [Joel suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747252/read-text-file-into-array-storing-ony-numerical-data/3747326#3747326).

Answer (score 0):

ReadAllLines does just what it says it does.  You have to iterate over the results.  To read the data you want directly, you have to write the code to use a System.IO.StreamReader (and it's ReadLine() function) or even just a base System.IO.FileStream.